# Swift - Assign View Controllers dynamically to the Tab bar

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My App is all based on API data. I am able to create a tab bar controller from api data but just ended up in confusion on how to create view controllers for each tab bar item dynamically. Here is the code so far -

```
    for i in 0..<navgTitle.count {

        print(navgTitle.count)

        controller1 = WeatherViewController()

        controller1.title = navgTitle[i]

        controller1.tabBarItem.title = navgTitle[i]

        controller1.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "AppIcon")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)


        array1.append(controller1)

    }

    print(array1)

    tt.viewControllers = array1

    self.view.addSubview(tt.view)

    self.tabBarControllr.moreNavigationController.show(tt, sender: self)

    tt.customizableViewControllers = []


}
```

In the above code, in the 'for' loop i want to create view controllers for each tab bar item (say 'HomeViewController', WeatherViewController' etc). I do not know how to do that and is it really possible? I can not create view controller classes manually because each app has their own tab bar items to show. Please suggest a way to do this..Thanks in Advance

Comment: How will you know which type of controller you want to create each time through the loop?

Comment: Based on the title array, 'navgTitle' in the above code gets the title from api which is the tab bar item that shows up in the tab bar. So, I want to create a view controller with same name so that the related actions can be handled in those view controllers. Hope this is clear, please let me know if you have any idea..thx

Comment: Can you create view controllers in your storyboard with identifiers that match possible values of `navgTitle` and then call `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier identifier: String)`?

Comment: Sorry, I am not using story boards in the app. And also, we have more than 15 tabs for each app, so it is not easy to manage story boards. That is why i want to create them dynamically, but could not find a way

Comment: Too bad...it would be easy with a storyboard.

Comment: Even with the storyboard i dont think it is possible because the tab bar items change every time with each app and so the identifiers fail.

Comment: It would be fine as long as you know the list of things they can change to.  It would never work if you can get titles that are invented on the fly.